# Why doesn't my class write to a text file?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my AddReservation Form code. Notice that I call the Piper.WritePiper() method and pass in the Name and Seat that the user enters. I'm not sure why this isn't working. I'm not getting any errors or anything. I am simply just wanting a user to be able to enter their name and seat that they would like to take on the plane and then update the file. Please tell me what I am doing wrong... Thank you in advance!!

```
public partial class frmAddReservation : Form
{
    public frmAddReservation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Seating> piperSeating = new List<Seating>();
    List<Seating> cessnaSeating = new List<Seating>();

    private void frmAddReservation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        piperSeating = Piper.GetPiperReservations();
        cessnaSeating = Cessna.GetCessnaReservations();
    }


    private void btnShowPiper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listFlight.Items.Add("Piper Seating Chart:");
        listFlight.Items.Add("");
        //loop through all the seats
        foreach (Seating plane in piperSeating)
        {

            // add the name of plane to the listbox
            listFlight.Items.Add(plane.Name + " " + plane.Seat);

        }
    }

    private void btnAddPiper_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Name;
        int Seat;

        if (DataValid())
        {
           Name = txtName.Text;
           Seat = Convert.ToInt16(txtSeat.Text);
           Piper.WritePiper(Name, Seat);
        }
    }

    private bool DataValid()
    {
        bool isOK = false;

        if (CheckSeat(txtSeat))
        {
            isOK = true;
        }

        return isOK;
    }

    private bool CheckSeat(TextBox tbox)
    {
        bool isOK = true;

        try
        {
            Convert.ToDouble(tbox.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            isOK = false;
        }
        return isOK;
    }
}
```

Here is my Piper.cs class:

```
public static class Piper
{
    private const string dir = @"Z:\Desktop\Windows 7 Files\C#.net\Reservations\Reservations\Reservations\";
    private const string path = dir + "PiperDat.txt";

    public static List<Seating> GetPiperReservations()
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        StreamReader textIn =
            new StreamReader(
                new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

        List<Seating> personList = new List<Seating>(); 
        while (textIn.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string row = textIn.ReadLine();
            string[] columns = row.Split(',');
            Seating person = new Seating();
            person.Name = columns[0];
            person.Seat = Convert.ToInt16(columns[1]);
            personList.Add(person);
        }

        textIn.Close();

        return personList;
    }

    public static void WritePiper(string Name, int Seat)
    {
        List<Seating> piperSeating = new List<Seating>();
        piperSeating = Piper.GetPiperReservations();


        StreamWriter textOut =
            new StreamWriter(
                new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write));
        foreach (Seating plane in piperSeating)
        {
            Name = plane.Name;
            Seat = plane.Seat;
            textOut.Write(Name + ",");
            textOut.WriteLine(Seat);
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Are you closing the file somewhere?

Comment: You forgot to flash and close.

Comment: I suspect that you text file is still being used after you read it first so it cannot write to it. You should use `using (var stream = new ...` on streams.

Comment: textOut.flush(); should do the trick.

Comment: No! Don't flush. Just close. Flush is almost always a mistake.

Comment: I have the close, but still not working...

Comment: First of all, `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` implement `IDisposable` and therefore should be in `using` blocks. Second, `FileMode.Open` requires the file to already exist; if your goal is to overwrite, it should be `FileMode.Create`. Third, what in God's name is going on with the assignment of the `plane` properties to the method args? And fourth, does the file actually get created? Does it not exist at all, or is it just empty? If it gets created (using `FileMode.Create`) but is empty, then the probably is that you don't have any data to write to it.

Comment: What doesn't work? Empty file? No file? Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `WritePiper` method.

It just reads the file and then writes it back, without any changes. The values in the parameters are ignored, the parameters are just used as temporary storage for the data when it is written to the file.

You need to include the values in the parameters as an item, either by adding it to the list, or by writing it to the file along with the items in the list.

Example:

```
Seating person = new Seating();
person.Name = Name;
person.Seat = Seat;
piperSeating.Add(person);
```

Comment: @user3658963: I added an example above.

Comment: Do I remove what I have in the Piper.cs and add this? Or add this to the AddReservation.cs?

Comment: @user3658963: You add it to the code in the method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of your issue might be having forgotten the closure of the file, in alternative you might force the text to `flush` with `textOut.Flush()`.

Try adding `textOut.Close()` at the end of the `WritePiper(...)` method.